# How does decision tree recognize the features from a given text dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree, text-processing

I have a binary classification text data in which there are 10 text features.

I use various techniques like Bag of words, TFIDF etc. to convert them to numerical.

I use **hstack()** to stack all those features together again after processing them.

After converting them to numerical feature, each feature now has large number of columns hence after conversion, my dataset has around 3000 columns.

My question is when I fit this dataset into decision tree classifier (sklearn), how does the classifier recognizes the columns which belong to  a particular feature?

For example first 51 column out of 3000 belong to US_states Bag of words.

Now, how will the DT recognize it?

PS: Data before processing is in pandas Dataframe.

After processing, it is a stacked numpy array being input in the classifier.

Comment: Welcome to SO; what you ask is unclear - what do you mean "recognize"?

Comment: Short answer: It won't. The DT does not care if a feature is called 'US_states' or something else.

Comment: DT has to know the categories in a feature and then decide how many child nodes does it want after calculating entropy of various features and finding out the information gain. That’s why I asked “recognize“

Comment: This is not about programming, but about the decision tree and tfidf algorithms, and so belongs on datascience.stackexchange.com or stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Decision Tree won't recognize from which features the attributes are coming.

Comment: Then how does it function? I am unclear here. For DT to work, it has to know the different categories in a feature, calculate Information Gain and create child nodes according to it. @Stergios

Comment: The attributes ARE the features for the Decision Tree.

Comment: Yes, but they are all mixed. I had 10 columns, after preprocessing I have 3000 columns. Now, if it doesn’t know which group of columns belong to a original feature, how would it function? How will it find the categories in that feature and calculate weighted  entropy to proceed further?

Comment: It doesn't need to know the original feature to work.